# TTrackBar > failed to paint background > How to fix?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

My environment: Windows 10 v1903

Using `TTrackBar`, when I change the color of the `TPanel` where the `TTrackBar` component is located above, the color is kept as the previous one.

For example, when I change the color of the `TPanel` from `clBtnFace` to `clWhite`, the color of the `TTrackBar` remains `clBtnFace`

Before change color of `TPanel`:
[image]

After change color of `TPanel`:
[image]

I tried following code, without success.

```cpp
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Panel1->ParentBackground = false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Panel1->Color = clWhite;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Panel1->Color = clWhite;

    Panel1->Repaint();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Panel1->Color = clWhite;

    Panel1->Invalidate();
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I would have expected `TrackBar1->Invalidate` (or `Repaint` or `Update`) to fix it, but no, no luck. Until I tried `TrackBar1->SetFocus`. Go figure! The slider bg remain lightgray, though. Btw, tested on Win 7 with XE 7

Comment: So, this is not specific to Windows 10. Thank you for your information.

Comment: Changing the size of the `TrackBar` also forces repaint

Comment: @KeremDThank you for your information. Changing size needs changing size back to the original. So I prefer using SetFocus() instead.

Comment: No problem. Tip: Triggering events by changing size can be done like this:`trkPtr->Width++; trkPtr->Width--;` in case you ever need it.

Comment: @KeremD Simpler than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Without clear solution, I may execute following.

```cpp
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Panel1->ParentBackground = false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Panel1->Color = clWhite;

    // Move focus to all of the TTrackBar
    //    Reason: Changing TPanel color does not change TTrackBar BGcolors
    for(int idx=0; idx < this->ComponentCount; idx++) {
        TComponent *cmpPtr = this->Components[idx];
        if (dynamic_cast<TTrackBar *>(cmpPtr) != NULL) {
            TTrackBar *trkPtr = (TTrackBar *)cmpPtr;
            trkPtr->SetFocus();
        }
    }

    // Set focus to myself (Button)
    if (Sender !=NULL) {
        TButton *btn = (TButton *)Sender;
        btn->SetFocus();
    }
}
```